# Permiso denegado - Python

Tags: python

Hola estoy teniendo problemas al intentar escribir un archivo .txt con el clásico:

```
file = open("Archivo.txt","a")
f.write()
f.close()
```

Cuando compilo mi computadora me da este aviso de error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Hola/Documents/practicas/Archivo.txt

Estoy utlizando Spyder de Anaconda en Windows.

¿A que se debe que no puedo abrir, ni escribir un archivo .txt en mi desktop?

Comment: Puede que no tengas permiso a la carpeta y al archivo, en tal caso abre anaconda en modo administrador, también asegúrate que el archivo este cerrado, o que otro programa no lo este usando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que todo estás tratando de escribir en "f", pero no existe ya que tenes el archivo instanciado en "file".
Mira [Acá habla de la Funcionalidad que intentas hacer](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)

```
file = open("archivo.txt","a")  
file.write("Texto nuevo a añadir")
file.close()
```

- open recibe como primer parámetro el archivo de texto existente.
  En segundo parámetro si lo que quieres es escribir más texto del que ya tienes recibe como parámetro "a".
- write recibe un parámetro que es el texto que quieres añadir, te fijaste si lo estas pasando?
- Si lo que deseas es crear el archivo de texto desde cero, open deberá recibir, como primer parámetro el nombre del archivo a crear "NombreArchivo.txt" y como segundo parámetro "x".

  f = open("myfile.txt", "x")

espero sea de ayuda la respuesta...