# TypeError: write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Tags: python-3.x, arduino

estoy intentando utilizar un código para ejecutar unos comandos gcode en un archivo Python para pasarlos a una librería GRBL de Arduino, pero me sale un error que no entiendo.

```
import serial
import time
def raw_input(x):
  input(x)

# Open grbl serial port
s = serial.Serial
s.port = 'COM3'
s.baudrate = 115200
s.open
# Open g-code file
f = open('grblgcode.txt','r');

# Wake up grbl
s.write("writing")
time.sleep(2)   # Wait for grbl to initialize 
s.flushInput()  # Flush startup text in serial input

# Stream g-code to grbl
for line in f:
    l = line.strip() # Strip all EOL characters for consistency
    print ('Sending: ' + l,)
    s.write(l + '\n') # Send g-code block to grbl
    grbl_out = s.readline() # Wait for grbl response with carriage return
    print (' : ' + grbl_out.strip())

raw_input("  Press <Enter> to exit and disable grbl.") 

f.close()
s.close()
```

Después de ejecutar el código sale el error "TypeError: write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'" en la línea 15.

Agradecería si alguien sabe que falla que me contara, que soy novato en el tema, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esta pregunta es muy parecida a [esta que ya está resuelta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321204/permiso-denegado-python/321230#321230):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
f = open('grblgcode.txt','r');
```

aca explica [como utilizar esta funcionalidad](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp).
open recibe 2 parámetros, nombre de tu archivo y:

- "r" - Leer: Valor por defecto. Abre un archivo para leer, error si el archivo no existe.
- "x" - Crear: creará un archivo, devolverá un error si el archivo existe.
- "a" - Agregar: creará un archivo si el archivo especificado no existe.
- "w" - Escribir: creará un archivo si el archivo especificado no existe.

---

tal vez a lo que te referias es que querías escribir en **'grblgcode.txt'**, pero tienes instanciado el open en "f", y con el parámetro 'r' de solo lectura, si lo que quieres es escribir más texto del ya existente utiliza 'a'.

```
f = open('grblgcode.txt','a')

f.write("writing")
```

---

intentas escribir en "s", pero mira esto, aunque sea se espera 1 parámetro que es el nombre del archivo, ya que por defecto viene "r", pero debes pasar el nombre del archivo:

```
s.open
```

open dice [como utilizar esta funcionalidad](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp), Está esperando algo como parámetro.

---

y estás intentando escribir sobre "s"

```
s.write("writing")
```

pero lógicamente te sale error porque anteriormente cuando lo abriste **s.open**, el no sabe qué hacer y mucho menos que archivo es, si quieres leer lo que ya existe, crear, agregar o escribir.

---

Por otro lado en python no se usa ";" terminando la línea de código como en otros lenguajes

```
f = open('grblgcode.txt','r');
```

Espero hayas entendido y sea de ayuda la respuesta.

Comment: De acuerdo, entonces el error era que no daba suficientes data para la función que estaba aplicando. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Exactamente, con mucho gusto :)